# How to insert into `std::map<string, double>* myMap`?

Tags: c++, pointers, stdmap

I have initialized a map like this:

```
map<string, double>* myMap = new map<string, double>();
```

*this declaration cannot change!*

I tried to insert into it like:

```
myMap["hi"] = 20.0;
```

and

```
myMap->insert ("hi", 20.0);
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating your map?

Comment: the signature is given in spec, so i cannot change it.

Comment: Dynamic allocation of the map is very strange and also the main cause of your difficulty.

Comment: @Const, yes, Oliort's answer helped. the guidelines say not to make a comment just to say "thanks" so i didn't, as the people are a little rude on this site sometimes, so i didn't want to break the rules! :) some of the other answers might've solved the question as well, but i stopped reading after it was resolved.

Comment: *as the people are a little rude on this site sometimes* Haha.. not all of them, and definitely not when [you ask per the guidelines provided in the community page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myMap` is the pointer in your case. Why do you allocate the map with `new`? Do it like this:

```
map<string, double> myMap;
myMap["hi"] = 20.0;
```

Or if you still want to allocate it dynamically, then dereference the pointer

```
(*myMap)["hi"] = 20.0;
```

or call `operator[]` with `->`:

```
myMap->operator[]("hi") = 20.0;
```

`insert` expects `std::map::value_type` which is `std::pair<const string, double>` in your case. Call it like this:

```
myMap->insert(make_pair("hi", 20.0));
```

or

```
myMap->insert({"hi", 20.0});
```

Note that if an entry with the same key already exists, using square brackets (either form) will replace the value of that entry, and using `insert` (either form) will do nothing and leave the previous value alone. *(from @aschepler comment)*

Comment: i updated the question. can you help me insert with the given declaration?

Comment: Note that if an entry with the same key already exists, using square brackets (either form) will replace the value of that entry, and using `insert` (either form) will do nothing and leave the previous value alone.

Comment: @aschepler Thank you, updated the answer from your comment.